# entity generation in gateway app of jhipster

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I am using entity sub generator to generate entities in my jhipster gateway app by giving path of microservice app.
but looks like I have to run sub generator for every entity in microservice . is there any way that it can read all the .json file and in micro service and generate all the entities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally do as following :

1. Copy repository ".jhipster" from the microservice repository into the Gateway repository
2. Generate the gateway with the following command:

   yo jhipster --with-entities

Comment: This is good..and works thanks a bunch for the trick. They can might as well add one more option to give path to list of json files of entities , which are generated in microservice app. May be after the question where it asks , which microservice you want to link this gateway to?..or something like do you want to generate the entities too? something like that.. or is it too much to ask :) as they have already done so much :)

Comment: @Mayurb If you type run `jhipster entity EntityName` on the gateway and it doesn't exist in the gateway's .jhipster folder, it will prompt you to enter a path to the microservice.  The only downside to this is that you have to generate each entity by itself

Comment: @JonRuddell Exactly!!, that's the reason I asked this question, to see how others are solving this problem of generating each entity by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your entities with jdl-studio you can specify microservices for them like in the [doc](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/#microserviceoptions).

```
microservice * with mysuperjhipsterapp except C
microservice C with myotherjhipsterapp
```

You can then generate the entitites with **jhipster import-jdl my_file.jdl** in both the gateway and the microservice.

You can skip entities from the gateway or the microservice by using  this options in your jdl file:

```
skipClient for A
skipServer for B
```